# Loading text files from any location in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I haven't been able to make the application load a file except by putting a direct link to the file hard-coded into the application or putting the file into the same part of the file system as the program.

I am using the console interface for this application, and I just need it to ask the user what file to load, let them tell the program which file to use, then execute the rest of the code and return the results. Putting a direct link and putting the file in the same directory works, but this solution is useless because I need to be able to select various files from anywhere on the computer. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: So you're building a command line tool, correct?

Comment: How do you load files? More details please.

Comment: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:someString] won't work for you?

Comment: Yes it is a command line tool. I am loading the file by creating a string and using stringWithContentsOfFile::encoding:error method. And I havent heard of your suggestion @jasper but I will look into it.